# How to make checkbox remain disabled if other control doesnt have value and enable if control has value in angular8

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

i have a checkbox fiels, where in i want to enable checkbox if the other control has value.
here i have 2 controls `amount and update received`. If update Received control has value in it, then user must be allowed to make checkin/checkout in the amount field.
If update requested control is empty/null then the amount checkbox must remain disabled and shouldnt allow user to checkin/checkout.

DEMO:
[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zwk7w1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

TS:

```
initEoForm() {
    this.eoInfoForm = this.FB.group({
      amount: ['', Validators.required],
      updateRequested:['']
    });
  }  


  public disableUpdate() {
    let disabled = true;
      if (this.eoInfoForm.value.updateRequested) {
        disabled = false;
        return false;
      }
    return disabled;
  }
```

HTML:

```
<form  [formGroup]="eoInfoForm">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
       <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
         {{disableUpdate()}}
                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="noNewBusiness"
                    formControlName="amount"  disabled="disableUpdate()">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="noNewBusiness">Update Received</label>
            </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

In order to see whether i get true or false value in html, i tried to check value  `{{disableUpdate()}}`. It is giving true or false values accordingly but even though i get true i am not able to checkin/checkout.

Comment: Did u solve with my suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tweaked it a little bit but I did it. You need setAttribute () and removeAttribute ().
I like to avoid if blocks, I prefer the ternary operator.

```
typing(event){
    let checkBox = document.getElementById('noNewBusiness')
    event.target.value == '' ? checkBox.setAttribute('disabled', 'true') : checkBox.removeAttribute('disabled')
  }
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-snqmbb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: i am not able to open this link, could you please post full answer or provide link again?

Comment: here, i want the checkbox to be enabled, if there is value in updateReceived field by default and not by typing.Can you please edit answer and send?

Comment: Maybe you mean you want the checkbox checked if there is text in the textbox? In case you only want the checkbox enabled, this is the way to enable and / or disable it, using the change event of the textbox

Comment: I ll provide to fix the url

Comment: I used your solution and tried and got fix, can you please validate once?https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-36xexh?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I fixed the link, try again

Comment: i am getting your old answer itself

Comment: in the stackblitx code you linked, you only set the checkbox in onInit, so that code will never be called again. You need to set the disabled attribute every time the textbox changes and check if there is text inside it, so as to decide whether to enable the checkbox or not. For this reason you need the event (input) that is called whenever the textbox text changes in value. so my solution is right for you. Don't forget to upvore and accept my solution, Thanks.

Comment: sure il vote and accept, have any idea how to keep focus on input when shift+tab is used?

Comment: (keydown.shift.tab)="agentCountyFocus('countyAgent')", can this be used?

Comment: Not now, I've never done it, even to solve your problem I needed time. I advise you to open a new topic ;) :D